# Replace foreach with for iteration in PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, iteration

**Problem:**

I have a foreach loop that works great for pulling images but when I try to replace it with a for loop it breaks the code and images.

**PHP code:**

```
// Create counter
$i = 0;

// Set number of photos to show
$count = 5;

// Set height and width for photos
$size = '100';

// Show results
foreach ($media->data as $data) 
{
    // Show photo
    echo '<p><img src="'.$data->images->thumbnail->url.'" height="'.$size.'" width="'.$size.'" alt="Instagram bild"></p>';

    // Abort when number of photos has been reached
    if (++$i == $count) break;
}
```

**Desired solution:**

To replace foreach with for and set counter in the for loop instead. This is probably really easy but for some reason I am completely stuck right now.

Comment: What is $media->data? Array? Could you index it somehow?

Comment: Where is the for loop? What have you tried?

Comment: @PeterKiss Yes, it's an array that pull images from Instagram using their GET /tags/tag-name/media/

Comment: Why do you not want to use `foreach`?

Comment: I think the code looks ugly using "if (++$i == $count) break;" to limit instead of limiting the number of photos through a for-loop.

Comment: [`foreach(array_slice($media->data, 0, $count) as $data)`](http://us.php.net/array_slice) looks more readable, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is if your `$media->data` variable could be indexed.

```
<?php
// Create counter
$i = 0;

// Set number of photos to show
$count = 5;

// Set height and width for photos
$size = '100';

// Show results
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
{
    $data = $media->data[$i];
    // Show photo
    echo '<p><img src="'.$data->images->thumbnail->url.'" height="'.$size.'" width="'.$size.'" alt="Instagram bild"></p>';
}
```

If not you have to use `foreach` but not `for` and exit from the loop when you reach the needed number of photos:

```
<?php
// Create counter
$i = 0;

// Set number of photos to show
$count = 5;

// Set height and width for photos
$size = '100';

// Show results
foreach ($media->data as $data) 
{
    // Show photo
    echo '<p><img src="'.$data->images->thumbnail->url.'" height="'.$size.'" width="'.$size.'" alt="Instagram bild"></p>';

    // Abort when number of photos has been reached
    if (++$i == $count) 
        break;
}
```

Also as it was written in the comments below it is a good idea to check the size of your `$media->data` variable if there are less than 5 images. You can make something like:

```
$count = (count($media->data) < 5)? count($media->data): 5;
```

Comment: I think you need to change `foreach` to `for`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much, I didn't think of using $i in data but it makes sense now.

Comment: This will fail if there are less than 5 images in the array.

Comment: @GolezTrol you are right but I wrote the answer as the bloke need it. I hope he will make some checks about that before setting the `$count` variable. +1 for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you determine the right count before entering the loop, you can save yourself a check on each iteration, seperating the initialization code from the loop code.

The `count` function and indexing like this will work, assuming `$media>data` is an array with a numeric index.

But I must admit I don't know why you would do this. The foreach loop is just as easy.

```
// Set number of photos to show
$count = count($media->data);
if ($count > 5)
    $count = 5;
// Set height and width for photos
$size = '100';

// Show results
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    // Use $i as an index to get the right item.
    $data = $media->data[$i];
    echo '<p><img src="'.$data->images->thumbnail->url.'" height="'.$size.'" width="'.$size.'" alt="Instagram bild"></p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$limit = 5;

for($i = 0; $i < count($media->data) && $i < $limit; $i++) {
    echo '<p><img src="'.$media->data[$i]->images->thumbnail->url.'" height="'.$size.'" width="'.$size.'" alt="Instagram bild"></p>';
}
```

Comment: Am I the only one who suspects the keys are not numeric?

Comment: any array can have two keys... the numeric one is always present

Comment: TIL a new thing about PHP ;-)

Comment: for($i = 0, $count = count($media->data); $i < $limit && $i < $count; $i++) { /* cleaner and faster */ }